# Assignment with two values in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm preparing a presentation on the linux kernel file [module_signing.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/module_signing.c) and on line 193 there is something I really don't get.
The line is:

```
    size_t modlen = *_modlen, sig_len;
```

How can you have two values on the right side of the assignment operator??

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You don't. You have a declaration of `modlen` with the initial value of `*_modlen`, and a declaration of `sig_len`. Both are of type `size_t`.